# Issue with one to one mapping delete

Tags: hibernate, mapping, one-to-one

i have an ejb module that is running with Hibernate ORM, i have two POJO for the model , 
here the first class :

```
@Entity
public class Vehicle implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Integer id;


public Vehicle() {

}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

}
```

and this is my second class :

```
@Entity
public class Transfer implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Integer id;
private Vehicle vehicle;    
public Transfer() {
}
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
@OneToOne
public Vehicle getVehicle() {
    return vehicle;
}
public void setVehicle(Vehicle vehicle) {
    this.vehicle = vehicle;
}
}
```

now whe i try to delete a Vehicle v1 instance i have this error :

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`pallasmobiledb`.`transfer`, CONSTRAINT `FK_9u0s4qxviu868ir3r7sgtbuqa` FOREIGN KEY (`cpo_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`))
```

can someone say whatihave wrong in my mapping mechanism ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When removing a vehicle, as it is a one-to-one mapping, transfer object will be deleted as well. 
You are deleting "Vehicle" entity, and your one-to-one is on "Transfer".
Two ways of doing this :

1 - Delete transfer object before deleting vehicle.

2 - You need to cascade the delete to the other entity. Annotate your @OneToOne like this :

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

BUT on "Vehicle" entity ... You have to change your mapping

Comment: thnaks Pras for your fast answer , but i want that i delete a vehicle without deleting the transfer, and i have to do the mapping in the transfer entity not in the vehicle entity , can i ?